# System audio pauses when game launches

Tags: ios, dragalia-lost

When I launch Dragalia Lost on my device, the game pauses all system audio other than the game itself. This continues to happen even if I mute all audio from within the game’s settings.

The device is an iPhone running iOS v11.4.1. The game is on version 1.0.1.

Does anyone have a way to get around this restriction?

---

Edit: If I attempt to restart the audio from the Control Center after it has been paused, it will resume. However, when anything is interacted with in the game, the audio is paused again.

Comment: Have you tried resuming playback from the control center once the game is started and on fullscreen?

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to note that in the initial question. See the edit I added.

Comment: I've run into this issue in the past with non-game apps like Facebook and Amazon. Whenever I started the app, my audio would stop even though the app wasn't starting any new audio. You might try asking in the Apple SE site, though they may say it's an issue only with specific apps and that the app maker may be the only one able to fix it.

Comment: @AdamV second this. You should try on AskDifferent, as this is more of an iOS issue than a game issue, though sometimes it's a bit hard to draw a line.

Comment: Ya I figured I’d ask here as this is the only application causing me this issue and that AskDifferent would probably just point me back over here or to just consult the dev. I’ll probably just consult the dev and update if I can find a solution.